# Extending an Attribute in Styles in Android

Tags: android

I have a `Button` as follows:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/previousQuestion"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
    android:text="@string/questions_activity_previous_button"
    android:onClick="previousButton_OnClick"
  />
```

but I want to add more styling attribute which makes the `Button` hard to maintain later on so instead, I was going to put them into its own `Style` resource.

The question is "How am I going to still use `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle`?" I tried to do the following but didn't work:

```
<style name="PreviousQuestionButtonStyle" parent="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
<style name="PreviousQuestionButtonStyle" parent="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle">
```

with this

```
<style name="PreviousQuestionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/ButtonBar">
```

Comment: It doesn't look the same as `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle`

Comment: `@android:style/ButtonBar` doesn't produce the same result as `android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle`. I wonder how this answer is marked correct.

Comment: For reasons I don't understand, this solution worked really well for me in my project.